# iSight/FaceTime camera not working after upgrade

Tags: macos, camera, osx-yosemite-beta, facetime, isight

right now i am running the OS X Yosemite beta 10.10, after upgrading my OS X i lost my camera, i tried everything in the forums, but nothing helped.

i can't FaceTime, or Skype or anything. normally i would take it in to an apple store, but the closest apple store to me is about 200 miles away.

since i am beta testing OS X Yosemite, i knew i was going to have some problems, but i need this to work

also; i also installed the update 2 days ago as it was recommended in the app store.

(not a hardware problem, was working perfectly before the upgrade and it is not found in the "system info> USB"); also not user specific.

Comment: Also not a programming problem, and is better suited for a site like SuperUser

Answer (score 1):

Open your `terminal` and type this command:

```
$ sudo Killall VDCAssistant
```

Now, go to your `Skype->Preferences->Audio/Video` and you can see the webcam working.
Have a good one!

Comment: Worked for me. If that's anyone else's problem, it's much better than resetting the SMC.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this problem persists even in the recent versions of OS X Yosemite. I also had this problem. So, the answer to solve it is basically resetting the SMC, which Apple provides instructions in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Now, I was not able to sort it even by resetting the SMC in a Macbook Pro 15 mid 2012. At least, not immediately. As I keep a few things connected in the USB ports, I believe it might have been the reason, so I closed all my applications (just in case), turned off the computer, unplugged all the USB and thunderbolt connectors (yes, including the LAN adaptor), as well as the earphone connector to speakers. THEN, reset the SMC (for non-removable battery computers, by pressing and releasing control-shift-alt-power [left shift] simultaneously while connected to power). For me, it worked.

It might be useful to remember that the SMC is the System Management Controller, that takes care of the hardware in a low-level, including i/o, keyboard backlight, speakers, camera... so, if you are going to reset it, it might make sense to release all the possible burden it might feel.

Answer (score 0):

[Resetting SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) is the only thing that solved the problem on my MBP Mid-2012.

The issue came about around the time I upgraded to High Sierra.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is solved with the newest update of OSX Yosemite. Just update through the Appstore app and everything will be normal.